# Steganography library or command line program

Tags: images

I have been using [Steghide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net/) for hiding data inside images. I recently found that the metadata of the cover file is removed during this process. Also there is no active development for this software since 2003. Although I haven't found any alternatives online / not enough feedback.

I am interested in hiding text and images inside other images. Anyone has experience using such software? Ideally it would be a mature solution which is still supported, compatible with Java or Windows + Linux command line.

This tool will be used by a java library.

Answer (score 4):

OpenStego is one that springs to mind on Linux - it also has a Windows client, and a Java executable (so will presumably work with Mac too). See here: http://openstego.sourceforge.net/index.html

It's still in active development, with the latest version having been released in April this year (2014).

Update:

It's in the reops (at least for Fedora and Ubuntu):
`sudo yum install OpenStego` or `sudo aptitude install openstego`

Comment: I *strongly* advise against this, as it uses DES and MD5 and is therefore *not* secure

Comment: @miniBill are you aware of alternatives?

Comment: No, sorry, I'd have written an answer. Anyway, you should always consider your threat model. Who are you protecting against?

Comment: If you want encryption in that too, I'd recommend using GPG and hiding that in the image. There's a decent guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gpg-to-encrypt-and-sign-messages-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Comment: @miniBill as long as its not immediately obvious something is hidden, its not a problem. Security is not important at current stage.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [OpenPuff](http://embeddedsw.net/OpenPuff_Steganography_Home.html) - a portable application which comes with a GUI. I have also written an article on how to download and use OpenPuff in my blog which you can read [here](http://www.articpost.com/hide-secret-messages-using-steganography/).

Comment: The tool is used from a javalibrary, so commandline access or API access are required. Added that to the description.